# Azure how can I secure SQL server VM from the WAN?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am new to azure and having trouble finding documentation on how I can switch off the WAN connection for a SQL Server VM.

I have setup a SQL Server VM on a Private Virtual Network: SQLServer1 (10.0.1.10)

I only ever want to connect to the server via private network using Site to Point VPN.

Therefore, is there any way to completely unplug the WAN connection?

I know I can setup rules to block ports in the firewall, but I really just want to disconnect the WAN for complete security and peace of mind.

Whats the best way to secure a VM from the WAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the the public endpoints from the VM configuration and no incoming traffic from public internet will ever reach it.
Endpoints: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/